# What can the function f look like?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Im reading Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed talking about Continuity and Category. Here is a corollary,
[image]

What puzzling here is, for example, f is continuous at all points of $\mathbb Q$ and then it seems to go that f should be continuous at any points of $\mathbb R$ cos $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and missing one point from $\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$ may lead f fails to be a continuous at all points of $\mathbb Q$. What can the function f look like? Can you show me with an example?

Comment: I think [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function) (also called the Ruler function) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Incidentally, a real-valued function of a real variable cannot be continuous precisely on the set $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an enumeration of the rationals then $$f(x)=\sum_{n:r_n\leq x}\frac{1}{2^n}$$ is continuous at each irrational and discontinuous at each rational. It is also monotone!

Comment: Why is it necessarily continuous at each irratioanl cos $\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is also dense in $\mathbb R$ and left limit at a irratioanl point may not be equal to right limit?

Comment: You can essentially choose a neighborhood small enough around each irrational such that you exclude all the 'problematic' rationals---those whose position in the well-ordering add to much weight in the summation.

Comment: There are jumps at each rational point. Thus at any given irrational there are infinitely many jumps around it; however, these jumps are really tiny---not enough to throw off continuity there.

Comment: Set A is dense in M => $Ball_ε$(x) ∩ A ≠ empty for every x∈M and every ε>0 and this means that any irrational point has been surrounded by rational numbers tightly and interlacing each other => it seems to be really impractical to exclude all the 'problematic' rationals.

Comment: f is continuous at a point x if for every ε>0 there is a δ>0(which depends on f,x,and ε) such that ρ(f(x),f(y))<ε whenever y∈M satisfies d(x,y)<δ. So it seems to be a little difficult to pass the δ-ε theorem in spite of the tiny jumps.

Comment: If $x$ is an irrational then $|f(x)-f(y)|=\sum_{n:y\leq r_n\leq x}\frac{1}{2^n}$ (assuming $y<x$). Since $x$ is irrational we can take intervals around it separating it from *any finite number* of rationals we please. We just have to exclude those $n$ so that our sum does not count those rationals. i.e. We make $|f(x)-f(y)|$ arbitrarily small by shrinking the radius around $x$.

Comment: you are right. Im sorry about that I've made a mistake here. My claim of "any irrational point has been surrounded by rational numbers tightly and interlacing each other" is not correct. I've reread the definition of dense and your interval centered at a irrational number x can exist there.

Answer (score 3):

My answer may be over-simple, but the function

$$ f (x) = \begin{cases} 0\, \, \, \mbox{ if } \, \, x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N} \\ 1 \, \, \, \mbox{ if } \, \,  x \in \mathbb{N}   \end{cases} $$

This function is continuous on the open set $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N}$, which is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$.

(Any continuous function on the entire $\mathbb{R}$-axis also satisfies the hypothesis.)

Comment: awesomeeeeeeeeee